# Tan castle? or whatever

Tags: set-identification

Bought a batch with quite a few tan bricks,

- 4 quarter circle panel
- 4 quarter circle brick
- 2 tower panel like 1/2 of 8-sided with arch window
- arches in 4 sizes
- slope 2:1, 3:1 & invert 1:1 (×1 & ×2)
- 1×1×1&5
- 1×2×1&5

Comment: While identification was possible in this case, it's often easier to identify parts by an image instead of their description.

Comment: I also made an edit to more easily distinguich which text refers to which part. Perhaps you can continue that edit for the last bullet point, because I don't know how to read it

Answer (score 7):

I made some guesses as to what parts you are describing. I particularly did not understand your description of the slopes. Luckily the other parts are enough to uniquely identify the set.

There are [six sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30246&v=0&in=S&srt=0&srtAsc=A&ov=Y) that use [30246 - Tan Panel 3 x 4 x 6 Turret Wall with Window](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30246&idColor=2#T=C&C=2).

[image: An image of the Lego part "Panel 3 x 4 x 6 Turret Wall with Window" in Tan]

While some of them also use the [30562 - Tan Cylinder Quarter 4 x 4 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30562&idColor=2#T=C&C=2),

[image: An image of the Lego part "Cylinder Quarter 4 x 4 x 6" in Tan]

only one uses both it and [48092 - Tan Brick, Round Corner 4 x 4 Macaroni Wide with 3 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48092&idColor=2#T=C&C=2).

[image: An image of the Lego part "Tan Brick, Round Corner 4 x 4 Macaroni Wide with 3 Studs" in Tan]

That set being:

**[4757-1 - Hogwarts Castle (2nd Edition)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=4757-1)**

[image: An image of the Lego set "4757-1 Hogwarts Castle (2nd Edition)"]

Comment: Think you're right, as I've also: big door, wings, 1×2 mod. log light grey & stairs.